# Multiple textbox validation using Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I submit my form, everything returns an error when no data is entered into it, except from firstname, can anyone find the error here?

```
var x=document.forms["register"]["firstname", "surname", "email", "username", "password1", "password2"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("All fields are required");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, that syntax is not right. You have to loop, query the DOM, or get them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it would be simple:

```
var allCorrect = true;
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.prevendDefault();
         $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
             if($(this).val() == "") {
                 $allCorrect = false;
                 alert("All fields are required.");
             }
         });
        if($allCorrect) {
            $(this).submit();
        }
    });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9t6rt/1/

Comment: But he's not using jQuery.

Comment: I've edited it, you have to include jQuery and put this code between some <script type="text/javascript">...</script> tags...

Comment: You should know the basics of HTML and JS if you want to do something like this..

Comment: if using this answer, would advise to use 
$(this).find('[type=text]')